# Don't understand the default implementation of Non-Overriding Descriptors in Python

Tags: python

I don't understand the design decision to render non-overriding descriptors ineffective when an instance attribute exists, e.g.

```py
>>> class Descriptor:
...     def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
...             return 4
...
>>> class Class:
...     attr = Descriptor()
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.attr = 'instance attr'
...
>>> Class().attr # why doesn't this return 4?
'instance attr'
```

To me, overriding descriptors make sense in that if we have a descriptor with `__set__`, then that `__set__` pretty much always gets used for something like `obj.attr = <new value>`.

Why aren't non-overriding descriptors this simple in the language, i.e. why isn't `__get__` pretty much always used when attributes are accessed, e.g. `obj.attr`?

Comment: `__get__` must be defined on the object that you're trying to get the property of (`Class` in this case), not the value of the property you're trying to get.

Comment: It's not clear why you would expect `4` instead of `'instance attr'` in this example; what effect do you think `self.attr = 'instance attr'` should have otherwise, or do you think it should have no effect (i.e. fail silently)?

Comment: @Aplet123 That's not true. If you remove the `self.attr = 'instance attr'` line then the code works as expected. See [this guide on descriptors in python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: @kaya3, I think `self.attr = 'instance attr'` should conduct traditional assignment to the instance attribute but any retrieval should still rely on the existing descriptor's `__get__`.

Comment: Why would that ever be the desired behaviour? If the descriptor doesn't have a `__set__` method, then it doesn't override what should happen when an attribute is assigned to, so you should expect attribute assignment to have its usual behaviour, i.e. if you assign a value then access it, you get the value you just assigned. If that is not the behaviour you want assignment to have, then the descriptor should define the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I get benefit from this:**

```
class Lazy():
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.name = function.__name__
        self.function = function
    
    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        print("get value by heavier __get__")
        obj.__dict__[self.name] = self.function(obj)
        return obj.__dict__[self.name]
        
class C:
    
    @Lazy
    def attr(self):
        # doing heavy calculation
        return "heavy calculation result"
```

```
>>> c = C()
>>> c.attr
get value by heavier __get__
heavy calculation result

>>> c.attr # get value by __dict__
heavy calculation result
```

In object's attribute lookup logic, `__dict__` has higher priority than non-data descriptor(maybe non-overriding descriptor in your question). In your first time trying to access attribute, since attribute doesn't exist in `__dict__`, attribute could be calculated in `__get__`  and cached it in traditional location(`__dict__`). By lower `__get__` priority, later lookup will get returned by `__dict__` directly.

`__get__` host complicated, heavy lookup logic inside. So, if you have two approaches to get identical value, the heavier one should have lower priority.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** Instance variable definition i.e. `self.attr = 'instance attr'` overrides class variable definition i.e. `attr = Descriptor()` whenever there's a name clash. Either change the names, or use the classname to access class variables like so

```py
Class.attr # instead of Class().attr
```

**Long Answer**

There's class variables and instance variables. Watch [this video](https://youtu.be/BJ-VvGyQxho) for a quick understanding. Class variables can be accessed using the classname or using an instance (if it  hasn't yet been overridden), but instance variables can only be accessed using instances.

In your example, the following line sets up a class variable `attr`, which if accessed will return `4`

```py
attr = Descriptor() # returns 4 because of __get__() definition
```

However with this next line inside the constructor of `Class` i.e. `__init__()`, you set up an instance variable with the same name `attr`, thus overriding the class variable.

```py
self.attr = 'instance attr'
```

Whenever you access the properties of an instance, first the instance variables are checked and only if it's not found then the class variables are checked. `Class()` creates  an instance, and so `Class().attr` will search for `attr` as an instance variable and since it's defined, the value of `'instance attr'` will be returned. If you hadn't defined it in `__init__()`, then it wouldn't be found, and so as the next step `attr` will be searched for as a class variable, and since that would be defined with the value `4`, it will be returned.